# Problems with TCP hole punching

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, hole-punching

I've tried to write a basic TCP hole puncher for a firewall in Python 3 using the principles outlined in [this article](http://www.bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/index.html).  I'm having trouble getting anything to connect, though.  Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import socket
import _thread as thread

def client():
    c = socket.socket()

    c.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    c.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)

    c.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), int(sys.argv[3])))
    while(c.connect_ex((sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])))):
        pass
    print("connected!")
    thread.interrupt_main()

def server():
    c = socket.socket()

    c.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    c.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)

    c.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), int(sys.argv[3])))
    c.listen(5)
    c.accept()
    print("connected!")
    thread.interrupt_main()

def main():
    thread.start_new_thread(client, ())
    thread.start_new_thread(server, ())

    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I decided to try the puncher on my local machine, so that I could capture all the traffic sent by both instances.  I first set up a loopback firewall:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j DROP
```

Then I launched two copies of the script:

```
left$ ./tcphole.py localhost 20012 20011
```

and

```
right$ ./tcphole.py localhost 20011 20012
```

I can see according to Wireshark that the SYN packets are being transmitted both ways:

[image: Wireshark capture]

But nothing ever prints "connected!" What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wait, wouldn't your firewall rules (specifically, rule #2) drop incoming `SYN` packets on `lo`? There are no "ESTABLISHED" or "RELATED" connections in your example, right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the behavior I am trying to work around. (The firewall is the adversary in this case.) SYN packets identified as RELATED should make it back through though.

Comment: And thanks for one of the most complete and clearly articulated questions I've seen for the while. (+1)

Comment: Haha, thanks!  I always try to thoroughly hash things out before asking so I don't look like an idiot.  Sometimes I end up looking like an idiot anyway, but you can only do so much.

Comment: I could be missing something obvious, but it's not entirely clear to me why you are expecting those SYN packets to be identified as RELATED.

Comment: Because they're coming from the same machine/port that I sent them to.  The first SYN will get dropped by the remote firewall, but the local firewall doesn't know that.

Comment: OK, I should read the paper (don't have time to do that right now).

Comment: Is this really hole punching or just plain TCP? Don't you need outbound connections on both ends for hole punching? You're connecting on one and accepting on the other...

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, bear in mind that I launch two copies of the script

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: Oh, I didn't realize, okay thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer turned out to be quite simple: *packets aren't considered `RELATED` if they aren't coming to the same IP address!*

Changing the `bind` lines to

```
c.bind('', int(sys.argv[3])))
```

(the `''` binds to the loopback address) fixes the problem entirely.